# whichever method you choose.. or whichever method that you choose

Tags: relative-clauses

1.*Whichever* *player* *scores* the highest number of points will be the winner.
2.It will be a difficult operation, *whichever* *method* *you* *choose*.
in above two sentences,can we use **that** or**which** after whichever player and whichever method? like,
1.Whichever player **that** **(which)** scores the highest number of points will be the winner.
2.It will be a difficult operation, whichever method **that** **(which)** you choose

Answer (score 2):

The use of *which* is not grammatical in either context. I believe the use of *that* would be grammatical in both instances (certainly the second) but, all things considered, you should eliminate *that* in both sentences so that they read:

> Whichever player scores the highest number of points will be the winner.
>
> It will be a difficult operation, whichever method you choose.

I think you may be confusing the use of which/that with a different scenario, written about here:

http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/103103whichthat.htm